# AAD Graph API Permission Issues

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I really hope someone can help me out with some permission issues I don't get on with.
I'm currently developing a web application with Azure Active Directory access. Everything is working fine so far.
Than I tried to implement a conversion from groups to roles which was working fine for a few tests.
But now - without changing anything in permissions I always receive:

> ":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"

Sometime this is with *requestId* and *date* sometimes it's not.

The code triggering this permission issue is:

```
var adClient = Instance.GetADClient(tenantID, signedInUserID, userObjectID);
var pagedCollection = await adClient.Users.GetByObjectId(userObjectID).MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
```

The same happens if I try to use

> GetMemberGroupsAsync()

So it seems to be a permission issue with retrieving members no matter of what kind.

Anyone got an idea of what am I missing or how I could debug this further?

Thanks very, very much for any idea!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shawn Tabrizi I found the error source.
Beware if you have issues like these, that you click on

> **Grant Permissions**

after modifying your Azure AD app permissions. Probably something many like me just oversee.

Here's the image Shawn has provided:
[image: **Grant Permissions** in Azure]

Thanks again Shawn for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This error implies that you have not requested or consented to permissions which grant your application access to those APIs.

When you register your application, you must define the permissions your app wants to the API it is calling. In this case, if you are calling the AAD Graph API, you must request for certain scopes, which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

Once you have selected the appropriate scopes for the API you need to call, you need to make sure to consent to your application, which ultimately allows your app to actually do the things it is requesting access for.

Note that some scopes specifically require an Admin of the tenant to consent.

If you are looking to debug issues related to permissions, a good place to start would be decoding your access token, and looking at the `scp` claims, which contains the scopes that have been granted to your application. I normally use [this site](http://calebb.net/) to decode the access token.

If you see the right scope in your token for the API call you are trying to make, then you should be good to go! Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hmm, I knew about all the scopes things and also tried to set all permissions for the app just to be sure - without success.
But what I noticed is the token doesn't have any scopes set - no `scp`

Comment: Did you consent to your application after you set new permissions? Can you share your token after removing personal information?

Comment: Ok, something's really getting weird here. I just reverted up to the point where I didn't use the groups (though as said it was working once), but now it's the same problem.
After setting new permissions (we're talking about permissions setting in Azure portal for my registered AD application right?!) I didn't have to consent anything new. :-?

Comment: Here's the token:

`{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "_UgqXG_tMLduSJ1T8caHxU7cOtc",
 kid: "_UgqXG_tMLduSJ1T8caHxU7cOtc"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.windows.net",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/REMOVED/",
 iat: 1489008789,
 nbf: 1489008789,
 exp: 1489012689,
 aio: "NA",
 appid: "REMOVED",
 appidacr: "1",
 e_exp: 10800,
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/REMOVED/",
 oid: "REMOVED",
 sub: "REMOVED",
 tid: "REMOVED",
 ver: "1.0"
}`

Comment: You have to force the consent prompt yourself. The app will not do it for you automatically. Also that token is an App Only token, which means you need to make sure to request specifically `application permissions`. If you are using "portal.azure.com" then there should be a button which says "Grant Permissions" which will grant consent to your app.

Comment: You mean the button when running the app the first time after configuring for Azure AD Authentication? If you mean that, yes that's what I always get.
At least now I know what it means if there are no scopes.
But never the less, what do you mean with "force the consent prompt"?? Sorry if my questions seem stupid, I'm still a bit new to all this and all the websites I've found either have only old state oder using simple REST demos. :(

Comment: If you are making app only calls, you actually need to look for `role` claims. `scp` claims are actually for delegated permissions. If you go into your app config page, for permissions, you need to click "grant permissions". See image [here](http://imgur.com/a/M6sIw).

Comment: Ok, I never used that "Grant Permissions" button as I thought it's the same as going into permissions and setting them. I think this was my problem. I'll check tomorrow (it's night time here already) and get back here. But I'm sure this was my problem the whole time.
So long thanks a lot for taking the time helping me!

Comment: You can force consent by adding `prompt=consent` or `prompt=admin_consent` in the URL when you are redirected to Azure AD.